# Placing an image in a jQuery tab?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Is there a correct way to place an image next to an **a** tag in a **li** used as a jQuery tab?

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Text</a>{I want the image here}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Using a div with the image as a background using inline-block works, but I've read that inline-block should be avoided.

```
<div style="display:inline" class="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh">
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I use `display:inline-block` pretty regularly. The only caveat being IE6 and IE7 only render it on natively inline elements, but `<a>` tags falls into that category. Is there any other reasons not to use it? [Source: quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you not just use a vertically aligned image?

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle" />
```

Comment: This works great. I was trying to use a jquery sprite icon but i can use an image instead.

Comment: If your image must follow the text, this is indeed the straightforward solution. By default, <img> is an inline element so you can integrate it in the text flow. You could also set a background image on the LI, aligned right, for a different result.

Comment: @Glauber Rocha Styling the LI would be a good idea for looks, but I'm testing out how it would work with a refresh button in the current selected tab.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is working great for me:

Tab HTML Code:

```
<div id="tabs">
     <ul>
    <li><a href="link1.php"><img src="image1.png" border="0">menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2.php"><img src="image2.png" border="0">menu item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3.php"><img src="image3.png" border="0">menu item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="link4.php"><img src="image4.png" border="0">menu item 4</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#tabs ul li img, #second ul li img {
vertical-align: middle;
margin-right: 8px;
}
```